# NLTK classification probability estimate with n-grams

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have the following code which estimates the probability that a string of text belongs to a particular class (either positive or negative).

```
import pickle
from nltk.util import ngrams
classifier0 = open("C:/Users/ned/Desktop/gherkin.pickle","rb")
classifier = pickle.load(classifier0)
words = ['boring', 'and', 'stupid', 'movie']
feats = dict([(word, True) for word in words])
classifier.classify(feats)
probs = classifier.prob_classify(feats)
for sample in ('neg', 'pos'):
    print('%s probability: %s' % (sample, probs.prob(sample)))
```

It yields the following:

```
neg probability: 0.944
pos probability: 0.055
[Finished in 24.7s]
```

The pickled classifier which I am loading already makes use of n-grams.

My question is:

How can I edit this code so that n-grams are incorporated into the probability estimate?

Answer (score 2):

Add the ngrams to your feature dict...

```
import pickle                                                                                                                                                                                              
from nltk.util import ngrams                                                                                                                                                                                   
fin = open("C:/Users/ned/Desktop/gherkin.pickle","rb")                                                                                                                                                        
classifier = pickle.load(fin)                                                                                                                                                                                 
words = ['boring', 'and', 'stupid', 'movie']                                                                                                                                                                   
ngram_list = words + list(ngrams(words, 2)) + list(ngrams(words, 3))                                                                                                                                           
feats = dict([(word, True) for word in ngram_list])                                                                                                                                                          
dist = classifier.prob_classify(feats)                                                                                                                                                                         
for sample in dist.samples():                                                                                                                                                                                  
    print("%s probability: %f" % (sample, dist.prob(sample)))
```

Example output...

```
$ python movie-classifer-example.py 
neg probability: 0.999138
pos probability: 0.000862
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the N-Gram classifier (with n used for training) you can generate the n-grams and classify them with the classifier, obtaining those probabilities.

To generate the new instances, use this example: (only for bi-grams and tri-grams).

```
import nltk
words = nltk.word_tokenize(text) # or your list
bigrams = nltk.bigrams(words)
trigrams = nltk.trigrams(words)
```